# printing out optional regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to print out values stored in a dictionary. These values were created from regular expressions.

Currently I have some optional fields but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly

`(field A(field B)? field C (field D)?)?`

I read a quick reference and it said that `?` means 0 or 1 occurrence.

When I try to search for a field such as `reputation` or `content-type` I get `None` because these are optional on my regex. I might have the wrong regular expression but I am wondering why whenever I search for an optional field `(...)?` it prints out `None`

my code:

```
import re

httpproxy515139 = re.compile(r'....url\=\"(?P<url>(.*))\"(\s+exceptions\=\"(?P<exceptions>([^\"]*))\"\s+error\=\"(?P<error>([^\"]*))\"\s+(reputation\=\"(?P<reputation_opt>([^\"]*))\"\s+)?category\=\"(?P<category>([^\"]*))\"\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation>([^\"]*))\"\s+categoryname\=\"(?P<categoryname>([^\"]*))\"\s+(content-type\=\"(?P<content_type>([^\"]*))\")?)?')

f  = open("sophos-httpproxy.out", "r")
fw = open("sophosfilter.log", "w+")

HttpProxyCount = 0
otherCount = 0

for line in f.readlines():
    HttpProxy = re.search(httpproxy515139, line)
    HttpProxy.groupdict()

    print "AV Field: "
    print "Date/Time: " + str(HttpProxy.groupdict()['categoryname'])
```

here is the full regex:

`(?P<datetime>\w\w\w\s+\d+\s+\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s+(?P<IP>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*httpproxy\[(?P<HTTPcode>(.*))\]:\s+id\=\"(?P<id>([^\"]*))\"\s+severity\=\"(?P<Severity>([^\"]*))\"\s+sys\=\"(?P<sys>([^\"]*))\"\s+sub\=\"(?P<sub>([^\"]*))\"\s+name\=\"(?P<name>([^\"]*))\"\s+action\=\"(?P<action>([^\"]*))\"\s+method\=\"(?P<method>([^\"]*))\"\s+srcip\=\"(?P<srcip>([^\"]*))\"\s+dstip\=\"(?P<dstip>([^\"]*))\"\s+user\=\"(?P<user>[^\"]*)\"\s+statuscode\=\"(?P<statuscode>([^\"]*))\"\s+cached\=\"(?P<cached>([^\"]*))\"\s+profile\=\"(?P<profile>([^\"]*))\"\s+filteraction\=\"(?P<filteraction>([^\"]*))\"\s+size\=\"(?P<size>([^\"]*))\"\s+request\=\"(?P<request>([^\"]*))\"\s+url\=\"(?P<url>(.*))\"(\s+exceptions\=\"(?P<exceptions>([^\"]*))\"\s+error\=\"(?P<error>([^\"]*))\"\s+(reputation\=\"(?P<reputation_opt>([^\"]*))\"\s+)?category\=\"(?P<category>([^\"]*))\"\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation>([^\"]*))\"\s+categoryname\=\"(?P<categoryname>([^\"]*))\"\s+(content-type\=\"(?P<content_type>([^\"]*))\")?)?`

Here is a sample input:

> Oct  7 13:22:55 192.168.10.2 2013: 10:07-13:22:54 httpproxy[15359]: id="0001" severity="info" sys="SecureWeb" sub="http" name="http access" action="pass" method="GET" srcip="192.168.8.47" dstip="64.94.90.108" user="" statuscode="200" cached="0" profile="REF_DefaultHTTPProfile (Default Proxy)" filteraction="REF_DefaultHTTPCFFAction (Default content filter action)" size="1502" request="0x10870200" url="http://www.concordmonitor.com/csp/mediapool/sites/dt.common.streams.StreamServer.cls?STREAMOID=6rXcvJGqsPivgZ7qnO$Sic$daE2N3K4ZzOUsqbU5sYvZF78hLWDhaM8n_FuBV1yRWCsjLu883Ygn4B49Lvm9bPe2QeMKQdVeZmXF$9l$4uCZ8QDXhaHEp3rvzXRJFdy0KqPHLoMevcTLo3h8xh70Y6N_U_CryOsw6FTOdKL_jpQ-&CONTENTTYPE=image/jpeg" exceptions="" error="" category="134" reputation="neutral" categoryname="General News" content-type="image/jpeg"

I ma trying to capture the entire log

However sometimes the `url` has many quotation marks in it which makes things confusing. Also in some logs, there is an extra `reputation` data field between `error` and reputation. `content-type` also does not always appear. Sometimes everything after the `url` data field is missing as well. This is why I added all the optional `?`. I am trying to take account of these occurrences and print `None` when necessary.

Comment: Next time you want to write a regex like this, use verbose mode. It'll be much more readable and much easier to debug.

Comment: If you don't give us some sample input, that makes it very hard to help—we have to imagine all the different ways your input could look and how that would work with your regexp. If you just give us sample input, desired output, and actual output, we can just debug it.

Comment: @user2357112 not sure how to write in verbose mode sorry! =/

Comment: `re.compile` and the other functions that take a regex also take a `flags` argument. Specifying [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) as a flag allows you to use whitespace and `#` comments in a regex and have them ignored by the regex parser. You'll need to escape any whitespace you actually want to match, but it's a small price to pay for not having to mash everything together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break your regex into two pieces:

```
....url\=\"(?P<url>(.*))\"
```

and

```
(\s+exceptions\=\"(?P<exceptions>([^\"]*))\"\s+error\=\"(?P<error>([^\"]*))\"\s+(reputation\=\"(?P<reputation_opt>([^\"]*))\"\s+)?category\=\"(?P<category>([^\"]*))\"\s+reputation\=\"(?P<reputation>([^\"]*))\"\s+categoryname\=\"(?P<categoryname>([^\"]*))\"\s+(content-type\=\"(?P<content_type>([^\"]*))\")?)?
```

The `.*` in the first part is greedy. It'll match everything it can, only backtracking if absolutely necessary.

The second part is one giant optional group.

When the regex executes, the `.*` will match everything up to the end of the string, then backtrack as necessary until the `\"` can match a quotation mark. That will be the last quotation mark in the string, and it will probably not be the one you wanted it to be.

Then, the giant optional group will try to match, but since the greedy `.*` already ate everything the giant optional group was supposed to parse, it'll fail. Since it's optional, the regex algorithm will be fine with that.

To fix this? Well, non-greedy quantifiers might help with the immediate problem, but a better solution is probably to stop trying to use a regex to parse this. Look for existing parsers for your data format. Are you trying to pull data out of HTML or XML? I've seen a lot of recommendations for [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).